# Create custom control with DataBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webusercontrol

I've created a `SearchResults` control that shows the results of a search.  This control has a repeating element (displaying the results) but also contains other elements which I've removed for this question.

Currently in the following example `DataItem` cannot be resolved.  I'm trying to work out how to make `DataItem` resolvable so I can use this control in the following way:

```
<Controls:SearchResults runat="server" id="Results">
    <RowHeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>User ID</td>
        </tr>
    </RowHeaderTemplate>
    <RowItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#((Models.User)Container.DataItem).ID %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </RowItemTemplate>
</Controls:SearchResults>
```

It is used in this way:

```
var searchResults = GetSearchResults();
Results.DataSource = searchResults ;
Results.DataBind();
```

### Search Results Control Code:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("DataSource")]
public partial class Search : UserControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), TemplateContainer(typeof(TemplateControl))]
    public ITemplate RowHeaderTemplate { get; set; }

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), TemplateContainer(typeof(TemplateControl))]
    public ITemplate RowItemTemplate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<object> DataSource { private get; set; }

    private bool DataBindingComplete { get; set; }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        if (DataBindingComplete) return;
        foreach (var obj in DataSource)
        {
            var newControl = new PlaceHolder();
            RowItemTemplate.InstantiateIn(newControl);
            RowItemContainer.Controls.Add(newControl);
        }
        DataBindingComplete = true;
        base.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Visible) return;

        OnInit(e);
        if (RowHeaderTemplate != null)
        {
            RowHeaderTemplate.InstantiateIn(RowHead);
        }
    }
}
```

With the markup:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Wrapper">

    <h2>Results</h2>    
    <table border="1">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="RowHead"/>
        <asp:Placeholder runat="server" Visible='<%#TotalResults == 0 %>'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100">
                    No results returned!
                </td>
            </tr>
        </asp:Placeholder>
        <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="RowItemContainer" Visible='<%#TotalResults > 0 %>'>

        </asp:PlaceHolder>        
    </table>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Please note this is a trimmed down example, simply using a `Repeater` control in place of it wont suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the TemplateContainer attribute for the Search control's RowItemTemplate property references TemplateControl, which doesn't have a DataItem property. Instead of using TemplateControl, create a SearchItem control that has a DataItem property:

```
public class SearchItem : Control, INamingContainer
{
    public object DataItem { get; set; }
}
```

In the Search class, change the TemplateContainer attribute for the RowItemTemplate property so that it references SearchItem instead of TemplateControl:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), TemplateContainer(typeof(SearchItem))]
public ITemplate RowItemTemplate { get; set; }
```

Also, instantiate SearchItem instead of PlaceHolder in DataBind:

```
var newControl = new SearchItem { DataItem = obj };
```

These are the minimum changes needed to get your example to work. However, your custom control won't automatically persist items across postbacks. To implement that functionality, I recommend that you study the source code for the [Repeater class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/Repeater.cs,a420b96b7e0bc83a).

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!